# Left behind photo

Tags: apollo-program

After several trips to moon there were several items left behind on the moon's surface, including foot prints. Is there any photo or registry of any of those items taken recently?

Comment: Foot tracks have been photographed from Moon orbit, but a single foot print is too small for that distance.

Answer (score 8):

The [Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/apollo/revisited/index.html) has photographed each of the Apollo landing sites in high resolution. You can also see them at this [page](https://history.nasa.gov/humanartifacts.html), and this [site here](http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/images?page=1&query=APOLLO). I won't post all of the images here, but here is one for Apollo 12/ Surveyor 3, for instance.

[image]

> Astronaut footpaths are marked with unlabeled arrows.

Answer (score 4):

Pearson's answer was really good, but I found a slightly higher resolution and more recent photo of the same landing site revealed in a [2011 media teleconference](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/news/lro-briefing-20110906.html). The photo in the other post was from 2009.

[image]

Here are other images from Apollo 14:

[image]

and Apollo 17:

[image]

Comment: The visibility of the footpathes is much better here.

Comment: See the comment I tried to leave for you but couldn't in [this meta post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1123/12102) I think your answer there is worth undeleting.